# jquery block ui not working as am unable to call dialog function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-blockui

In belowcode i have used dialog function of jquery blockui. but its not working. when i press ctrl+space am unable to find that function which will show me  a dialog box.
please suggest some code using which i can create a dialog box. I want to disable the parent html page and only focus on the display dialog opened.

```
<html>
    <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootmetro/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootmetro/scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert('loaded');
    $('#button1').click(function()
    {
        $('#dialog1').dialog();


    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="button1" class="" type="button" value="Button">

<div id="dialog1">
This is dialog
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [modal](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) option

```
$('#dialog1').dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AWXVd/)

Answer (score 0):

To use [blockUI dialog](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog) you must use it this way.

```
 $.blockUI({ message: $('#dialog1'), css: { width: '275px' } });
```

You are trying to use jQuery dialog. To use jQuery dialog you must include [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) to your html